# Yii2 - viaTable join returns error

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to write **hasMany** relationship, but I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'[[licences.id = userKeys.licence_id]] = `licences`.`0` LEFT JOIN `userKeys` `use' at line 1

The SQL being executed was: 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `activityLogsUserActivity` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `activityLogsUserActivity`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `licences` ON `activityLogsUserActivity`.[[licences.id = userKeys.licence_id]] = `licences`.`0` 
LEFT JOIN `userKeys` `userKeys` ON `licences`.`user_id` = `userKeys`.`user_id`
```

The code:

```
public function getKeys()
    {
         return $this->hasMany(UserKeys::classname(), ['user_id' => 'user_id'])
            ->select('licences.licenceName, userKeys.*')
            ->from(['userKeys' => UserKeys::tableName()])
            ->viaTable(Licences::tableName(), ['licences.id = userKeys.licence_id']);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `['licences.id = userKeys.licence_id']` to `['licences.id' => 'userKeys.licence_id']`

Answer (score 0):

```
['licences.id = userKeys.licence_id']
```

should be a key-value pair, like

```
['id' => 'licence_id']
```

and it should not be necessary to declare the table name there, have a look at the docs

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#viaTable()-detail

> The link between the junction table and the table associated with $primaryModel. The keys of the array represent the columns in the junction table, and the values represent the columns in the $primaryModel table.